# ImageView in LinearLayout changes size when background changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I am creating an app and one of the aspects is just a pretty simple rating section. It's quite simple at the moment with just getting the average rating and displaying that using stars. I have 5 ImageViews displayed in a Linear Layout and the background of each Imageview changes to one of three star drawables depending on the rating score. Here is the layout structure of the stars:

```
starFilled = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_rate_24);
          starOutline = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_outline_24);
        halfStar = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_half_24);enter code here


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/overall_rating_stars"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/overall_rating_title">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overall_rating_s1"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_outline_24"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overall_rating_s2"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_outline_24"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overall_rating_s3"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_outline_24"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overall_rating_s4"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_outline_24"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overall_rating_s5"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_outline_24"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

And here is how I am changing the background of the stars:

```
private void mapRating(ImageView star1, ImageView star2, ImageView star3, ImageView star4, ImageView star5, double rating) {
        if (rating == 0.0) {
            star1.setBackground(starOutline);
            star2.setBackground(starOutline);
            star3.setBackground(starOutline);
            star4.setBackground(starOutline);
            star5.setBackground(starOutline);
        } else {
            if (rating <= 0.50) {
                star1.setBackground(halfStar);
            }
            if (rating > 0.50) {
                star1.setBackground(starFilled);
            }
            if (rating > 1.00 && rating <= 1.50) {
                star2.setBackground(halfStar);
            }
            if (rating > 1.50) {
                star2.setBackground(starFilled);
            }
            if (rating > 2.00 && rating <= 2.50) {
                star3.setBackground(halfStar);
            }
            if (rating > 2.50) {
                star3.setBackground(starFilled);
            }
            if (rating > 3.00 && rating <= 3.50) {
                star4.setBackground(halfStar);
            }
            if (rating > 3.50) {
                star4.setBackground(starFilled);
            }
            if (rating > 4.00 && rating <= 4.50) {
                star5.setBackground(halfStar);
            }
            if (rating > 4.50) {
                star5.setBackground(starFilled);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's certainly not the most refined or elegant way of changing the stars but my problem is at least one of the stars seems to change in size when running the application and viewing the ratings: [smaller 5th star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4n1R.png), [smaller 4th star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vVDg.png),[smaller 2nd star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILHQL.png)

I have tried a multitude of different things such as changing from background to src in both XML and Fragment. As well changing the scaleType for each but to center|crop or center or even XY. However, none of it seems to be fixing it. All the stars have the same height (50dp), width (50dp), and viewport height/width (24). Help would be greatly appreciated as this is a minor yet frustrating problem.

Comment: I suggest you add more of your layout. Obviously your `LinearLayout` is inside a `ConstraintLayout`. The culprit might be outside of what you are showing here.

Comment: Use `android:src` for showing  the image instead of the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RatingBar to rate instead of creating your own. I have attached two links for your reference. Please check it out.

[Google developer link for ratingbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar)

[Youtube link for RatingBar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpNJhJF3gW8)

Comment: Wow thank you very much this is exactly what I needed. I tested changing from backgrounf to src and that fixed the height but messed with the width. Using your suggestion will make fix all this. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly upvote this answer if it was helpful. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the src in layout.xml?
try it...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).